# How to combine mutations to create or login user in django-graphql-jwt?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I use VueJS and Django + [django-graphql-jwt](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt) (which returns tokens). I want to use email\password fields for registration and for login. On a server I want to check if provided email already exists -> use `django-graphql-jwt`'s mutation `token_auth = graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()` to return token + message, else -> create a new user with provided email and password and return this user  + message.

For now I have:

```
# schema.py

import graphene
import graphql_jwt

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    class Arguments:
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, password, email):
        user = get_user_model()(
            username=email.split('@')[0],
            email=email,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return CreateUser(user=user)

# Want to combine two mutations here
class GetOrCreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    class Arguments:
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, password, email):
        # Return token
        if get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            # Just an idea, what I want to get here (to be returned to VueJS)
            return {'token': graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field(), 'msg': 'Token Generated'}

        # Create new user
        else:
            user = CreateUser(???)
            return {'user': user, 'msg': 'User is Created'}


class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
    get_or_create_user = GetOrCreateUser.Field()
```

I tried different variants, but it seems I do not understand fully graph's workflow or\and what magic `Graphene` does (its documentation not informative).

Can anyone show me, how can I re-use in if\else block already created code (`CreateUser` class and `graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I did not find how I can call mutation from mutation (how I can call `class CreateUser` from `class GetOrCreateUser`, so I decided to integrate `CreateUser` to `GetOrCreateUser`).
2. I did not find, how I can call `graphql_jwt` via a code like (example is taken from [graphene doc](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/execute/))

   ```
   schema = graphene.Schema(...)
   result = schema.execute('{ name }')
   ```

   so I decided to take token directly via Python instead of Python\GraphQL.

Below is the full code:

```
# schema.py (the root one)
import graphene
import graphql_jwt
import apps.users.schema


class Query(apps.users.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Mutation(apps.users.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    verify_token = graphql_jwt.Verify.Field()
    refresh_token = graphql_jwt.Refresh.Field()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

and

```
# users/schema.py
import graphene

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()


class GetOrCreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    """
    mutation {
      getOrCreateUser(email: "test@domain.com", password: "YourPass") {
        token
        user {
          id
          email
          isActive
        }
      }
    }
    """

    user = graphene.Field(UserType)
    token = graphene.String()

    class Arguments:
        password = graphene.String(required=True)
        email = graphene.String(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, password, email):
        token = ''

        # Return token
        if get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=email)
            token = get_token(user)

        # Create new user
        else:
            user = get_user_model()(
                username=email.split('@')[0],
                email=email,
            )
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

        return GetOrCreateUser(user=user, token=token)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(UserType)

    def resolve_users(self, info):
        return get_user_model().objects.all()
```

FrontEnd can define the state by checking `token` field. If empty, than user is created, if there is something, than user exists and just logged in.

Answer (score 4):

[django-graphql-auth](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does exactly what you’re looking for.

It extends django-graphql-jwt to handle all user account related actions.

here is the registration mutation from the [docs](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#register):

```sh
mutation {
  register(
    email:"skywalker@email.com",
    username:"skywalker",
    password1: "supersecretpassword",
    password2:"supersecretpassword"
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken
  }
}
```

It already return the token and the refresh token from the django-graphql-jwt.

Than you can use to login, from the [docs](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#obtainjsonwebtoken):

```py
mutation {
  tokenAuth(
    # username or email
    email: "skywalker@email.com"
    password: "supersecretpassword"
  ) {
    success,
    errors,
    token,
    refreshToken,
    unarchiving,
    user {
      id,
      username
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I'm the author

Answer (score 1):

You can create one function and use it in both mutations:

```
def get_or_create_user(password, email):
    if get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        return ('user or token or other data that you need in'
                'mutation, this is not mutation return value')
               # {'token': graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field(),
               # 'msg': 'Token Generated'}

    # Create new user
    else:
        user = get_user_model()(
            username=email.split('@')[0],
            email=email,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return ('user or token or other data that you need in'
                'mutation, this is not mutation return value')
               # {'user': user,
               # 'msg': 'User is Created'}
```

Comment: It would not work like that with graphene. 1) `graphql_jwt.ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()` does not return values (does not return string), it returns object. 2) As far as I understand the type of returned item must be the same as declared under `class GetOrCreateUser(graphene.Mutation):`, but I do not know which type should I use for `dict`.

Comment: @TitanFighter im just copied your code. The purpose of this function is - combine if/else logic for your two mutations...